# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number & not 'Dimension' & 'NaN' in pooling layer output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a global std pooling 1D layer since keras does not provide this layer. Basically i just copied from source code of GlobalAveragePooling1D from the source code and replace the 'backend.mean' with 'backend.std'. Here is my code,

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as backend
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.utils import conv_utils
import tensorflow as tf

class GlobalPooling1D(Layer):
  """Abstract class for different global pooling 1D layers."""
    def __init__(self, data_format='channels_last', keepdims=False, **kwargs):
        super(GlobalPooling1D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=3)
        self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
        self.keepdims = keepdims

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        input_shape = tf.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list()
        if self.data_format == 'channels_first':
          if self.keepdims:
            return tf.TensorShape([input_shape[0], input_shape[1], 1])
          else:
            return tf.TensorShape([input_shape[0], input_shape[1]])
        else:
          if self.keepdims:
            return tf.TensorShape([input_shape[0], 1, input_shape[2]])
          else:
            return tf.TensorShape([input_shape[0], input_shape[2]])

    def call(self, inputs):
        raise NotImplementedError

  def get_config(self):
    config = {'data_format': self.data_format, 'keepdims': self.keepdims}
    base_config = super(GlobalPooling1D, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

class GlobalStdPooling1D(GlobalPooling1D):

      def __init__(self, data_format='channels_last', **kwargs):
          super(GlobalAveragePooling1D, self).__init__(data_format=data_format,
                                                       **kwargs)
          self.supports_masking = True

      def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
          steps_axis = 1 if self.data_format == 'channels_last' else 2
          if mask is not None:
              mask = tf.cast(mask, inputs[0].dtype)
              mask = tf.expand_dims(
                  mask, 2 if self.data_format == 'channels_last' else 1)
              inputs *= mask
              return backend.std(inputs, axis=steps_axis, keepdims=self.keepdims)
          else:
              return backend.std(inputs, axis=steps_axis, keepdims=self.keepdims)

def model():
    input_m = Input(shape = (1000, 750))
    con1d_m_5 = Conv1D(768, 5, activation='relu')(input_m)
    std_m_5 = GlobalStdPooling1D()(con1d_m_5)
    output = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(std_m_5)

    model1 = Model(inputs = [input_m], outputs = [output])
    model1.compile(loss = ['categorical_crossentropy'], optimizer=Adam(1e-5))
    print(model1.summary())
    return model1

model = model()
```

when i ran this code, I got the error on the topic. I printed the layer shape one by one to debug the error, and I found that the globalStdPooling1D layer, which is supposed to show (None, 768), shows (?, 768). the question mark is being considered as Dimension, not numbers, that may cause the problem. Is there any way to overcome this issue using the global pooling layer?

2. I might be too aggressive here, but I did figure out a way to tackle the problem above.
   I used Lambda(lambda x : backend.std(x)) to replace the Global std pooling

```
def model():
    input_m = Input(shape = (1000, 750))
    con1d_m_5 = Conv1D(768, 5, activation='relu')(input_m)
    std_m_5 = Lambda(lambda x : backend.std(x, axis = 1))(con1d_m_5)
    output = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(std_m_5)

    model1 = Model(inputs = [input_m], outputs = [output])
    model1.compile(loss = ['categorical_crossentropy'], optimizer=Adam(1e-5))
    print(model1.summary())
    return model1
```

the model can be constructed, but the issue is the output of that layer are all 'NaN', which caused no gradient come back. is there any way to tackle this issue or I should tackle the globalStdPooling1D layer to get it done?

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed the problem. Keras version are different between the source code on the official website and the one installed in my laptop. The earlier version only accepts the number or 'None' from the previous layers, but the current one takes Dimension value, that caused the error. I just need to update the keras I had and problem fixed.

The 2nd problem seems pretty tricky, I gave the data generator for training, instead, just used data one by one, it works fine. I got to dig into the data processing code for further debugging but the code in the question has no problem.